# How to find the room of two users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am implementing the chatroom data structure.

room.rb

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :room_user_ships
  has_many :users, through: :room_user_ships
end
```

room_user_ship.rb

```
class RoomUserShip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :room_user_ships
  has_many :rooms, through: :room_user_ships
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "rooms", force: true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
create_table "room_user_ships", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "room_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I can get the user's rooms and the room's users

```
room = Room.find(100)
room.users
```

My problem is when a user Alex (User id: 10001) send a message to user Emma (User id: 10002), I have to find the room id of these users, but I don't know how to do it.

Iterating all rooms works but is not a good idea.

```
user = User.find(10001)
receiver = User.find(10002)
user.rooms.each do |room|
  if room.users.include?(receiver)
    the_room = room # find it!
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: one other way to do this is using collect `user.rooms.collect{ |room|  room if room.users.include?(receiver) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have the 2 users, what about something like:

```
room = Room.joins(:room_user_ships) \
           .where(room_user_ships: { user_id: [user.id, receiver.id] }) \
           .where(room_user_ships: { room_id: user.room_ids }).first
```

Comment: Is this really correct? The first 'where' selects all rooms which have room_user_ships from user or receiver (the array translates to SQL IN operator) , and the second 'where' basically reduces this set to the rooms of the user. So I think the statement can sometimes return rooms which are not connected to the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveRecord `joins()` method lets you find objects according to conditions in connected objects. Here it gets a little more complicated because the user and the receiver both have their own `RoomUserShip`. So you need to join two times with the same table. I think you can take advantage of the implicit join created by the `User.rooms` relationship, so this will hopefully work:

```
user.rooms.
  joins(:room_user_ships).
    where( room_user_ships: {user_id: receiver.id} ).first
```

Have a look at the SQL which Activerecord generates. It should have two different joins.

Comment: Your answer has syntax error, it should be `user.rooms.joins(:room_user_ships).where( room_user_ships: {user_id: receiver.id} ).first`. However, when I run this, I get nil. Generate SQL: `Room Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "rooms".* FROM "rooms" INNER JOIN "room_user_ships" "room_user_ships_rooms" ON "room_user_ships_rooms"."room_id" = "rooms"."id" INNER JOIN "room_user_ships" ON "rooms"."id" = "room_user_ships"."room_id" WHERE "room_user_ships"."user_id" = $1 AND "room_user_ships"."user_id" = 10002  ORDER BY "rooms"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 10001]]`

Comment: @楊萬皇  I asked author.. :)

Comment: ActiveRecord seems to not distinguish correclty between the two joins. The where clause is wrong: WHERE "room_user_ships"."user_id" = $1 
     AND "room_user_ships"."user_id" = 10002 
With $1 as 10001 this of course gets us nil. In SQL I would use give the tables aliases with AS. I don't know how to do this with ActiveRecord.

Comment: It' true. I found this SQL works, but don't know how to do it by ActiveRecord. `SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" INNER JOIN "room_user_ships" "k1" ON "k1"."room_id" = "rooms"."id" INNER JOIN "room_user_ships" "k2" ON "rooms"."id" = "k2"."room_id" WHERE "k1"."user_id" = 10001 AND "k2"."user_id" = 10002 ORDER BY "rooms"."id" ASC LIMIT 1`